# play mp3 and control volume with rstats shiny

Tags: r, shiny

any tips how to play a mp3 file and control the volume via shiny?
I can do both with javascript. But how to execute a javascript function from shiny?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs. check this out. might be useful. though i suppose it is very incomplete